# HierarchyId: mapping in native entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, hierarchyid

I'm trying to define my schema using code-first fluent configuration, and I'm running into a problem while configuring a column type hierarquyId.
I´m try define with Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId. not success.

Suggestions?

How use hierarquyId  natively in entity framework code first ?

sorry, my English is not good

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: see this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId/